# redux pushing to state

Tags: javascript, redux

Can someone explain why i'm not getting the expected result here?

```
const initialState = {
  items: ['cats'],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.push('dogs'),
  };
};

console.log(reducer()); // { items: 2 }
```

**Expected result** : `{ items: ['cats', 'dogs'] }`
**Actual result**: `{ items: 2 }`

PS: I think i skipped this course on js/redux, or my brain doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Because `Array#push` mutates the array and returns the new length of the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push . That's how arrays have always worked. You want `items: [...state.items, 'dogs']` or `items: state.items.concat('dog')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're directly mutating the state with `push`, use array spread instead:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: [...state.items, 'dogs'],
  };
};
```